# Is the point-wise limit of simple functions a measurable function?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Let $X$ and $Y$ be  topological  spaces. By a simple function $\phi: X\to Y$ we mean a finite range Borel measurable function.

Q. Is the point-wise limit of a  sequence of simple functions a Borel measurable function?

Comment: This question is better suited for MSE, in fact it´s answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327081/how-to-prove-limit-of-measurable-functions-is-measurable/1327089)

Comment: @Saúl Rodríguez Martín, It is  concerned with set-valued functions not complex valued! I have no clue to find a proof

Comment: The link that you referred does not work for set valued functions.

Comment: Your notation is unknown to me. What is the definition of a finite range Borel measurable function?

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t read correctly. In general the statement seems false, you can take the real line in the cofinite topology, $\mathbb{R}'$, and define the functions $f_n:\mathbb{R}'\to\mathbb{R}'$ by $f_n(x)=n\;\forall x$, and then take as a limit some non measurable function you want (the Borel sets would be the countable sets and their complements, and any function $f:\mathbb{R}'\to\mathbb{R}'$ is a pointwise limit of that sequence). In metric spaces it seems to work though.

Comment: @Saúl Rodríguez Martín  Thanks,  Nice argument.

Comment: In fact the standard definition is actually: simple function=finite range, Borel measurable function=linear combination of characteristic functions of Borel subsets. But where are the set-valued functions?

Comment: @PietroMajer I was confused at first too, but I think he means that the function takes values in any set $Y$, not just in $\mathbb{C}$ (although that´s not what people usually mean when they say set-valued).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is Yes provided the topology of $Y$ is such that for each non-empty open set $O\subset Y$ there is a strictly increasing sequence $(O_k)$ of open sets:
$$
\overline O_k\subset O_{k+1}\subset O,\quad k=1,2,\ldots,
$$
with $\bigcup_kO_k=O$. For suppose $(f_n)$ is a sequence of Borel functions from $X$ to $Y$ with pointwise limit $f$. With $O$ and the $O_k$ as above,
$$
f^{-1}(O)=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{m=n}^\infty f_m^{-1}(O_k).
$$
This shows that $f^{-1}(O)$ is a measurable subset of $X$. Because the Borel $\sigma$-field on $Y$ is generated by the open sets, it follows that $f$ is Borel measurable.

In particular, the condition above is true if $Y$ is metrizable.

Comment: I do not think that you need a **strictly** increasing sequence with **strict** inclusions. And in fact that "**strict**" need not hold in metrizable spaces (e.g. if $Y$ is finite).

Comment: I tried to indicate what I meant by *strictly* in the display just below that word.  In particular, my use of $A\subset B$ follows the convention allowing for $A$ and $B$ to coincide.